# Application_Error in Global.asax Doesn't Fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-asax

Locally the application error executes fine(catches errors then puts it into a database or sends it via mail). But when I add it up to our website it doesn't execute the codes under application_error.Any help why it doesn't fire?

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)




    Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Current.Request.Cookies("id")
    Dim Code As HttpCookie = Current.Request.Cookies("code")
    Dim ErrorMsg() As String
    If cookie Is Nothing Then
    Else

        Dim cDBConnection As clsDBConnection = New clsDBConnection(GetConnection, enumEgswFetchType.DataReader)
        If IsNothing(Code.Value) Then
            ErrorMsg = {0, Request.UserHostAddress.ToString, Me.Session.SessionID, Context.Request.RawUrl, Date.Now, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Message, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.GetType.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Data.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Source, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.TargetSite.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.StackTrace}
            cDBConnection.InsertErrorLog(ErrorMsg(0), ErrorMsg(1), ErrorMsg(2), ErrorMsg(3), ErrorMsg(4), ErrorMsg(5), ErrorMsg(6), ErrorMsg(7), ErrorMsg(8), ErrorMsg(9), ErrorMsg(10))
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx")
        Else
            ErrorMsg = {Code.Value, Request.UserHostAddress.ToString, cookie.Value, Context.Request.RawUrl, Date.Now, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Message, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.GetType.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Data.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.Source, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.TargetSite.ToString, Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException.StackTrace}

            cDBConnection.InsertErrorLog(ErrorMsg(0), ErrorMsg(1), ErrorMsg(2), ErrorMsg(3), ErrorMsg(4), ErrorMsg(5), ErrorMsg(6), ErrorMsg(7), ErrorMsg(8), ErrorMsg(9), ErrorMsg(10))
             Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx")
        End If
        'End If

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what your existing code looks like..? also could you state whether the app runs, hangs, errors, etc... when you put it out on the target server

Comment: Anything in Event Log?

Comment: Edited. It works fine locally, I even tried sendEmailHtml it works but when I upload it in my website it doesnt work

Comment: @DJKRAZE I throw an exception on main homepage stil it doesnt work or even a 404 page

Comment: @LukeHutton event log?

Comment: when doing `Redirects` the expected page is not always guaranteed you probably have an error somewhere else either in the `PostBack` or if you are checking `IsPostBack` what you need to do is put breakpoints in the code and step thur the code especially on the `Page_Load` Event or somewhere where  you have a validated field or a control that has `Causes PostBack` property's set to true.. I have seen this before many times in my code where It was the opposite it would do the `PostBack` but also had a  nagging error on the page.. start there

Comment: even the database function doesn't work